# rhc setup gives syntax error

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am following this [openshift client tools](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-debian-ubuntu.html#client-tools) for ubuntu. I've just created an application on rhcloud and I am trying to install client tools to get my code installed on rhcloud. I get the following error

```
viju@viju:~$ rhc setup
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:236: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
        .compact
         ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:462: odd number list for Hash
          title: @title,
                ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:462: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
          title: @title,
                ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:463: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          percent_complete: percent_complete,
                           ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:464: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          progress_bar: progress_bar,
                       ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:465: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          step: @step,
               ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:466: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          steps_remaining: steps_remaining,
                          ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:467: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          total_steps: @total_steps,
                      ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:468: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          time_elapsed: '%0.2fs' % time_elapsed,
                       ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:468: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:470: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
        }.merge! @tokens
         ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.3.0/lib/commander.rb:27
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.34.2/lib/rhc.rb:30
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.34.2/lib/rhc/cli.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.34.2/bin/rhc:18
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:19
```

Could someone tell what exactly I am missing in, why there be a syntactual error or at least a pointer to get me installed the application on rhcloud.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are getting seem to be because you are using an older version of ruby that does not support the new syntax like

```
symbol: "value"
```

Try upgrading to a newer version of ruby, at least 1.9.3

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess this should work. I haven't had luck installing ruby1.9.3 **properly** but that's different issue altogether. I'll mark it correct once I check it. For now I am using Openshift's eclipse plugin which got my work done.